# Embeding inline images in script

Tags: html, powershell, change-password

I've found this password expiry script in which I would like to embed local images at the beginning (header) of the HTML message and at the end (footer), but whatever approach I take images in the received emails are still displayed with a red cross.

```
$PPNConfig_DebugLevel = 0

$PPNConfig_NotificationTimeInDays = 100
$PPNConfig_SMTPServerAddress = "smtp.somedomain.local"
$PPNConfig_FromAddress       = "admin@somedomain.local"
$PPNConfig_BodyIsHtml        = $true
$PPNConfig_DirectoryRoot = "LDAP://DC=somedomain,DC=local"
$PPNConfig_MaxPageSize = 1000

function Configure-Notification-Subject($nName, $nNumDays)
{
    return "$nName, your password will expire in $nNumDays days."
}

function Configure-Notification-Body-Html($nName, $nNumDays)
{

    $bodyHtml = "
Body text here....
    "

    return $bodyHtml
}  

function Get-Domain-MaxPassword-Age
{
    $ThisDomain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
    $DirectoryRoot = $ThisDomain.GetDirectoryEntry()

    $DirectorySearcher = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$DirectoryRoot
    $DirectorySearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=domainDNS)"
    $DirectorySearchResult = $DirectorySearcher.FindOne()

    $MaxPasswordAge = New-Object System.TimeSpan([System.Math]::ABS($DirectorySearchResult.properties["maxpwdage"][0]))

    return $MaxPasswordAge
}

function Get-Users-With-Expiring-Passwords
{
    $UsersToNotify = @()

    $DirectoryRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($PPNConfig_DirectoryRoot)
    $DirectorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($DirectoryRoot)
    $DirectorySearcher.filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)))"
    $DirectorySearcher.pagesize = $PPNConfig_MaxPageSize

    $MaxPasswordAge = Get-Domain-MaxPassword-Age
    $MaxPasswordAgeDays = $MaxPasswordAge.Days

    $DirectorySearchResult = $DirectorySearcher.FindAll() |
    ForEach-Object -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" `
    -Process `
    {
        $PwdChanged = ([adsi]$_.path).psbase.InvokeGet("PasswordLastChanged")

        $DaysTillExpiring = $MaxPasswordAgeDays - ((Get-Date) - $PwdChanged).Days 

        if ($DaysTillExpiring -le $PPNConfig_NotificationTimeInDays)
        {
            $UserToAdd = New-Object psobject

            $UserToAdd | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value ([adsi]$_.path).name[0]
            $UserToAdd | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Email" -Value ([adsi]$_.path).mail[0]
            $UserToAdd | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "DaysLeft" -Value $DaysTillExpiring

            $UsersToNotify += $UserToAdd
        }

    }

    return $UsersToNotify
}

function Send-Email-Notification-Of-Expiry($nName, $nEmail, $nDaysLeft)
{
    $SmtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($PPNConfig_SMTPServerAddress)

    $NewMail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $NewMail.From = $PPNConfig_FromAddress
    $NewMail.To.Add($nEmail)
    $NewMail.Subject = Configure-Notification-Subject $nName $nDaysLeft

    if ($PPNConfig_BodyIsHtml)
    {
        $NewMail.IsBodyHtml = $true
        $NewMail.Body = Configure-Notification-Body-Html $nName $nDaysLeft
    }
    else
    {
        $NewMail.IsBodyHtml = $false
        $NewMail.Body = Configure-Notification-Body-Plain $nName $nDaysLeft
    }

    $SmtpClient.Send($NewMail)
}

$UsersToNotify = Get-Users-With-Expiring-Passwords

foreach ($User in $UsersToNotify)
{
    if ($PPNConfig_DebugLevel -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Host $User
    }
    else
    {
        Send-Email-Notification-Of-Expiry $User.Name $User.Email $User.DaysLeft
    }
}
```

Comment: So where exactly in this script are you attempting to configure the header and footer?

Answer (score 0):

here is how I did it.  I'd put it here but I already have a whole blog post on it. I send email notifications with stuff like this all the time it is super useful

http://winsysadm.net/send-mail-with-inline-embedded-images-with-powershell/